# Find the count of non null values in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried

`df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count").show`

but this works only for integers. I tried a for loop as below:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
var count_val = ListBuffer[Long]()

for (i<-0 to column_names.length) {
    count_val += df.select(column_names(i)).where(column_names(i)+" is not null").count
}
```

Is there any other faster way to do it?
Dataframe is of type org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

Comment: which version of spark are you using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `def count(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column` & This function will return count of not null values.

It will give you same result as `df.describe()` for `count`.

```
 df.select(df.columns.map(c => count(col(c)).as(c)):_*).show(false)
```

Spark `2.4.2` version

`df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count").show` is working for columns of type `string`.